# How run Symfony project without virtual host?

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I have my own server how can I run symfony project without creating virtual host.

Comment: Is this server only going to run ONE project?

Comment: Hi Riggs,

Thanks for quick reply

No there is multiple project hosted there. We are use  that using link like 202.x.x.x/projectname.

Comment: what is the type of own server that run your project xampp or wamp server?

Comment: Symfony can use the server built into PHP 5.4.  Check out the link here:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/built_in_web_server.html

Answer (score 4):

Do I really need VirtualHost for symfony development?

It all depends on personal preference, if you want to open project with virtual host you can configure it, if not keep like this

**localhost/project_folder/web/app_dev.php.**

Your symfony app will run with the above URL. I have hosted so many apps on Cloudways and I ran my apps with the URL like this

**phpstack-21306-71265-234521.cloudwaysapps.com/fos/web/admin**

so I don't need to setup a virtual host either on live server.

Comment: If i crate the new controller then it will give me the 404 error

Comment: You need to create routes for the controller methods and call the route in your browser URL. you will get the response. I have published bunch of symfony tutorials you can learn here: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/php/symfony/

Comment: Good, when you create more routes try to access with /web/your_route this will look more clean. And accept my answer as solution :)

Comment: You don't need /app_dev.php or whatever if you are using a standard install of symfony as it comes with an [.htaccess](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/3.3/web/.htaccess) file that takes care of the rewrites. All you need to remember is that web is considered symfony's 'document root' by default. And that should be your entry point. (or in case of vhosts/live most likely your docroot). so your source files are not 'public'. see https://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_architecture.html that explains it better.